# C++ concatenation between literal and constant

Tags: c++, literals, string-concatenation

I am new to C++ and I want to know why the line below is not correct. (SERVER_NAME has been defined as a constant)

```
L"Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Data Source=" << SERVER_NAME << ";"
```

I get these errors:

```
error C2296: '<<' : illegal, left operand has type 'const wchar_t [...' 
error C2308: concatenating mismatched strings
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

operator<< is not a concatenation operator, it's a special overloaded operator by stream types to let you send data to stream. It only works if you're using a stream.

You have two options here. First, you can use a std::wstring:

```
std::wstring(L"Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Data Source=") + SERVER_NAME + L";";
```

Or you can use a wstringstream (from the `<sstream>` header):

```
std::wstringstream stream;
stream << L"Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Data Source=" << SERVER_NAME << L";"
```

Use `stream.str()` to get the resulting string in that case. The stream approach has the advantage that you can use it even if not all the things you want to concatenate are already strings.

If you're printing to an existing stream (like wcout), you can just skip the stringstream and use that directly, of course.

As other answers have pointed out, you can use `L"Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Data Source="  SERVER_NAME L";"` if SERVER_NAME is a constant create with #define. If it is a `const wchar_t*` that won't work however.

Comment: Incur runtime overhead just to glue three constants known at compile time? Don't think so.

Comment: The `L"string1" CONSTANT L"string2"` approach only works if the constant is a #define rather than an actual const, though.

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me and yes, the constant is a #define

Comment: What about if the final result I need is a LPCOLESTR instead of a std::wstringstream?

Comment: Use the stream's `str()` method to get a `std::wstring`, and the `c_str()` method of that to get a `const wchar_t*` for the string, which is what `LPCOLESTR` is a typedef of. You should just be able to pass the string; unlike `BSTR`, I don't think `LPOLESTR` requires any special allocation method.

Answer (score 2):

`<<` and `>>` are not concatenation operators, but rather bitwise shifting operators, something that is totally unrelated.

It's confusing for beginners because they have been overloaded for `cout` and `cin` to mean something completely different.

Concatenation of string literals in C and C++ is done without a special operator, so just type:

```
L"Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Data Source=" SERVER_NAME L";"
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be that `SERVER_NAME` is not a wide-character string. However, what's definately broken is that your `";"` is not a wide-character string. Try using `L";"`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to concatenate this string use std::stringstream

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Data Source=" << SERVER_NAME << ";";
std::string final = ss.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::wstring connectionString = "Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Data Source=";
connectionString += SERVER_NAME + ";";
```

Make sure `SERVER_NAME` is defined as wide-character string, something like this:

```
const wchar_t *SERVER_NAME = L"testdb";
```

Or,

```
std::wstring SERVER_NAME = L"testdb";
```